# C#: Terminate other threads if one thread fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, task

Is there any way to stop execution of other concurrent threads if one of the threads fail? I am working on a ASP.NET MVC website which will make heavy use of API calls. Instead of sending too many API requests in sequential fashion, I am creating threads, each thread consuming one API call. If any of the thread fails, I want to kill other threads. How can I do that? I used `Task.WaitAll` but it allows all other threads to execute even if one thread fails. Please help.

UPDATE: 
To simulate real time scenario, I have created a console app. Please refer below code. I want to make fifth thread fail. After fifth thread fails, I want all other running threads to stop.

```
public class Program
{
        static int[] delays = { 3, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 };
        static int[] ids = new int[10];
        static Task[] tasks = null;
        static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        static IList<int> threadsExecuted = new List<int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();

            try
            {
                tasks = ids.Select(id => MyTaks(id)).ToArray();
                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in Main::\nMessage: " + exception.Message +
                    "StackTrace: " + exception.StackTrace +
                    "InnerException: " + exception.InnerException);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nThreads executed: " + string.Join(", ", threadsExecuted.OrderBy(id => id).ToArray()));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nExit..");

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static async Task MyTaks(int id)
        {
            var delay = delays[id - 1] * 1000;

            Console.WriteLine("Thread id #" + id + " started with delay " + delay + " seconds.");

            CancellationToken cToken = tokenSource.Token;

            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(delay);

                if (id == 5) //Fail
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling..");

                    throw new Exception("Thread id #" + id + " failed.");
                }
            }, cToken);

            task.Start();

            await task;

            Console.WriteLine("Thread id #" + id + " executed.");

            threadsExecuted.Add(id);
        }
```

}

Comment: it would certainly help other people to understand your problem better, if you would post some of the code that you already wrote

Comment: You can use CancellationToken (1 for all threads), Call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() on fail and check  IsCancellationRequested

Comment: @ Leonid Malyshev: How can CancellationToken work in case of Web API? Is it that API request once initiated can be stopped using CancellationToken?

Comment: yes, try this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of sending too many API requests in sequential fashion, I am creating threads, each thread consuming one API call.

This approach will pretty much destroy any scalability for your server. Instead of parallel concurrency (multiple threads), you should use asynchronous concurrency (multiple operations). Your API code would use `HttpClient.GetAsync` and pass a `CancellationToken`.

So, your test code would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();

  try
  {
    tasks = ids.Select(id => MyTaks(id)).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in Main::\nMessage: " + exception.Message +
                "StackTrace: " + exception.StackTrace +
                "InnerException: " + exception.InnerException);
  }

  lock (threadsExecuted)
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nThreads executed: " + string.Join(", ", threadsExecuted.OrderBy(id => id).ToArray()));

  Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nExit..");

  Console.Read();
}

private static async Task MyTaks(int id)
{
  var delay = delays[id - 1] * 1000;

  Console.WriteLine("Task id #" + id + " started with delay " + delay + " seconds.");

  CancellationToken cToken = tokenSource.Token;

  // Production code would use `await httpClient.GetAsync(url, token)` here.
  await Task.Delay(delay, cToken);

  if (id == 5) //Fail
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling..");
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    throw new Exception("Thread id #" + id + " failed.");
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Thread id #" + id + " executed.");
  lock (threadsExecuted)
    threadsExecuted.Add(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stphen for your advice. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Stephen. Want to ask you one question regarding await `httpClient.GetAsync(url, token)`. Will `token` cause API request initiated to stop it's execution on API server? Or only the operation at client side would fail?

Comment: @TejasSutar: It will cancel the *request*. The server will detect this and will terminate the request thread *if* the handler is synchronous; if the handler is asynchronous, it can take a `CancellationToken` to detect this situation.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Stephen. You saved me from Production disaster.. :-)

Comment: It would be more elegant to handle the cancel call in a continue action `task.ContinueWith( t => source.Cancel(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted );` - now you only need to raise an exception inside the task and everything will be handled

Comment: @SirRufo: The cancelling can easily be moved outside `MyTasks`, but `await` is more correct and maintainable than `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this if you want to cancel a collection of task

```
 // Define the cancellation token.
  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken token = source.Token;

  Random rnd = new Random();
  Object lockObj = new Object();

  List<Task<int[]>> tasks = new List<Task<int[]>>();
  TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(token);
  for (int taskCtr = 0; taskCtr <= 10; taskCtr++) {
     int iteration = taskCtr + 1;
     tasks.Add(factory.StartNew( () => {
                                   int value;
                                   int[] values = new int[10];
                                   for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++) {
                                      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                      lock (lockObj) {
                                         value = rnd.Next(0,101);
                                      }
                                      if (value == 0) { 
                                         source.Cancel();
                                         Console.WriteLine("Cancelling at task {0}", iteration);
                                         break;
                                      }   
                                      values[ctr-1] = value; 
                                   }
                                   return values;
                                }, token));   

  }
  try {
     Task<double> fTask = factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), 
                                                  (results) => {
                                                     Console.WriteLine("Calculating overall mean...");
                                                     long sum = 0;
                                                     int n = 0; 
                                                     foreach (var t in results) {
                                                        foreach (var r in t.Result) {
                                                              sum += r;
                                                              n++;
                                                           }
                                                     }
                                                     return sum/(double) n;
                                                  } , token);
     Console.WriteLine("The mean is {0}.", fTask.Result);
  }   
  catch (AggregateException ae) {
     foreach (Exception e in ae.InnerExceptions) {
        if (e is TaskCanceledException)
           Console.WriteLine("Unable to compute mean: {0}", 
                             ((TaskCanceledException) e).Message);
        else
           Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.GetType().Name);
     }
  }
  finally {
     source.Dispose();
  }
```

**Update:** To cancel web api using cancellation token 
You need to accept cancellation token in API

```
[AsyncTimeout(150)]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(TimeoutException),
                                    View = "TimeoutError")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GizmosCancelAsync(
                       CancellationToken cancellationToken )
{
    ViewBag.SyncOrAsync = "Asynchronous";
    var gizmoService = new GizmoService();
    return View("Gizmos",
        await gizmoService.GetGizmosAsync(cancellationToken));
}
```

Asynchronous action methods returning `Task<ActionResult>` are cancelable, that is they take a `CancellationToken` parameter when one is provided with the `AsyncTimeout attribute`.

[msdn reference](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken)

Comment: You miss to check for cancellation in the loops

Comment: The task is not cancelable by only assigning the token. That token is only used by the scheduler if the task should start. Once started you had to check the token by yourself

Comment: `if (ct.IsCancellationRequested == true)` should `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`

Comment: But `source.cancel()` will raise a request for cancelling the task

Comment: No it will just set the IsCancellationRequested flag in the token - thats all. Simply call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested inside the loops and you are fine

Comment: Many thanks @Eldho..!! I used TaskFactory as directed in your code & achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the version of [Task.WaitAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321280(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx).

Further information - [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How will this help here? And the token will only cancel the wait for tasks not the tasks.